# What is the iff condition for a set to have Supporting Hyperplane?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, optimization, convex-analysis

Of course, a *compact* set has [Supporting Hyperplanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane) (SH), a *convex* set with boundary has SH. Those conditions are sufficient, but not necessary.

What is the sufficient and necessary condition for a given set to have at least one supporting hyperlane?

Does the set $\{(x,y)|y>tan(x)\}$ has a supporting hyperplane?

For example, the set $\{(x,y)|x,y\in\mathbb Z\}$ does not have a supporting hyperplane, because any line in $\mathbb R^n$ cannot bound the set.

$\{(x,y)|x,y\in\mathbb N^*\}$ does have one where $\mathbb N^*$ is the set of positive naturals.

Comment: Can you give a definition of "supporting hyperplane"? In particular, why does $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ not have one? And what is $\mathbb N^*$?

Comment: $\mathbb R^2$ is convex, but does not have a supporting hyperplane according to Wikipedia's definition.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you for mentioning this, Sir. Updated. I guess a convex set with boundary suffice?

Comment: Why do you think any line in $\mathbb R^2$ cannot bound $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N$? As far as I can see the line $y=0$ (or $y=1$ if $0\notin\mathbb N$ for you) satisfies Wikipedia's definition.

Comment: The epigraph of the  tangent function does not have any SH.

Comment: @HenningMakholm my bad!

Comment: I doubt that this question has a simple answer.

Comment: @MoisheCohen $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: One usually considers elementary functions on their natural domains. In this setting, $x=-\pi/2$ is not an SH. But if you restrict the domain to $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ then indeed, $x=-\pi/2$ is the unique SH for the epigraph.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks for the teaching! Any hints/ideas to solve the original question?